# Unexpected token error

Tags: jquery

I have a small script and it throws Unexpected token error on line 2 and firebug says missing : after property id $('#hubmeter').click(function() {...}

```
$(document).ready({
$('#hmeter').click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});

});
```

html

```
<body>
<div id="hmeter">
<img src="meter.png"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `function ()` in `$(document).ready({`.

```
                  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hmeter').click(function() {
      alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As MДΓΓ БДLL said, you are writing the document ready wrong. IT should be like this

```
$(function(){
  $('#hmeter').click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
   });

});
```